# Aurelia css binding with function

Tags: javascript, aurelia

What would be the right way to allow using `function` instead of adding code inside class bind just like this line `<div class.bind="isSuccess ? 'success' : 'error'">${message}</div>` in app.html? This kind of example when using in knockout will update respectively the class binding even though the observable is inside a function.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=d2b120bcd3d6a8157f4d4c9bf247988b**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <div class.bind="getColor()">${message}</div>
  <div class.bind="isSuccess ? 'success' : 'error'">${message}</div>

  <button click.delegate="toggleColor()">toggle color</button>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  message = 'hello worlds';
  isSuccess = false;
  toggleColor() {
    this.isSuccess = !this.isSuccess;
  }

  getColor() {
    return this.isSuccess ? 'success' : 'error';
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gist.host/run/1479356763275/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-bundle/v1.0.3/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jdanyow/aurelia-bundle/v1.0.3/config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```css
/* Styles go here */

.success {
  background-color: green;
}

.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a getter function when binding to computed properties. For instance:

**JS**

```
import {computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {
  message = 'hello worlds';
  isSuccess = false;
  toggleColor() {
    this.isSuccess = !this.isSuccess;
  }

  @computedFrom('isSuccess') //use @computedFrom to avoid dirty-checking
  get getColor() {
    return this.isSuccess ? 'success' : 'error';
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class.bind="getColor">${message}</div>
```

Comment: It [works](https://gist.run/?id=b939325a584a979c2e6ad28f02290a24). Thanks.